# when I trying to make captcha with kcaptcha in cakePHP 2.0 , I have a error like this :

Tags: php, captcha, cakephp-2.0

when I trying to make captcha with kcaptcha in cakePHP 2.0 , I have a error like this :
`call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'CaptchaComponent' does not have a method 'initialize'`

anyone help me?

Comment: as stated, it looks like your class CaptchaComponent does not have a method called initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your CapchaComponent.php file like this:

```
<?php
class CaptchaComponent extends Object
{
    function initialize()
    {
    }
    function beforeRender()
    {
    }
    function shutdown()
    {
    }
    function startup(&$controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    function render()
    {
        App::import('Vendor', 'kcaptcha/kcaptcha');
        $kcaptcha = new KCAPTCHA();
        $this->controller->Session->write('captcha', $kcaptcha->getKeyString());
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component classes must extend Component instead of Object in CakePHP 2.x